# output gets printed but it has a extra empty line

Tags: python

I'm trying this simple code to print a txt file with a if condition.
Code works fine, but when the output gets printed but it has a extra empty line. how to fix that?

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'Efficient AP Image Upgrade ..... Enabled' in line:
            break
        print(line)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The line in `line` contains a newline character at the end. To avoid the `print` function to add another newline (the default behaviour), you should call `print('line', end='')` to specify that you don't want the extra newline.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `print` on strings that already have a final newline -- in fact now that the question has been tidied up we can see that this is the case because you are using an iterator over `file`, and this will produce a sequence of lines that end with newline characters (except possibly the last line if it does not have a newline in the input file).

Note that after the data items, the `print` function will write an additional newline by default (more specifically, it will write the value specified by the `end` parameter, which defaults to a newline).

Possible approaches:

Use `sys.stdout.write` (does not append newline):

```
sys.stdout.write(text)
```

Use `print` but set it to write empty string instead of newline at the end:

```
print(text, end='')
```

Remove any newlines before printing (in principle this may include newlines in the middle of the string but because your strings come from an iterator over file object, there shouldn't be any):

```
print(text.replace('\n', ''))
```

Remove any leading or trailing whitespace (including newlines) before printing - note that this may include other spaces:

```
print(text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

print() by default, creates a new line when you execute that. For your notice, try using

```
print(line,end='')
```

or

```
print(line,end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the trailing new line you can strip new lines from the right side of the line:

`print(text.rstrip('\n'))`